# Prove that for any natural number $ \geq 2$ $ \langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle = \langle y_1, ..., y_n\rangle $ iff $ x_1 = y_1, ..., x_n = y_n $

Tags: logic, induction

My first step was to figure out which set I am trying to show is $(\{2\}, F)$-inductive.
So I came up with this:

$ A = \{ n \geq 2 : \langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle = \langle y_1, ..., y_n\rangle $ iff $ x_1 = y_1, ..., x_n = y_n\} $

From here, I figure I need to show first the base case, where n = 2. Or, prove that:

$ \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle = \langle y_1, y_2\rangle $ iff $ x_1 = y_1, x_2 = y_2$

My question isn't about this proof. But for reference I prove this by reducing it into set theory using Kuratowski's definition:

$ \langle x, y \rangle $ = {{x}, {x, y}}.

And then prove the relevant set identity using the principle of extensionality for sets.

I figure my next step is to prove the inductive step. Which I formulate as follows:

If $ n \in A $, then $n + 1 \in A $

As a conditional, I begin this proof by assuming the truth of the antecedent for some arbitrary n:

$  k \in A$.

Given the definition of A above, this gives me:

$ \langle x_1,..., x_k \rangle = \langle y_1,..., y_k\rangle $ iff $ x_1 = y_1 ,..., x_k = y_k$

And now show how from this we can get to this:

$ \langle x_1,..., x_k, x_{k+1} \rangle = \langle y_1,..., y_k, y_{k+1}\rangle $ iff $ x_1 = y_2 ,..., x_k = y_k, x_{k+1} = y_{k+1}$

This is the part I am a bit confused on. For in many of the examples of mathematical induction I've been able to track down, this step is executed using algebraic operations. But I'm not entirely sure what the analog of those operations are here.

I tried my best to mirror these examples and started by just supposing I can take both of the sequences and add an item to them. So, for example,

$ \langle x_1,..., x_k \rangle $

becomes

$ \langle x_1,..., x_k, x_{k+1} \rangle $

I then exploited the recursive definition of n-tuples to rephrase this as:

$ \langle \langle x_1,..., x_k \rangle x_{k+1} \rangle $

And finally, I exploited the results of the Kuratowski definition and rephrased this as:

$\{\{\langle x_1, ... , x_k\rangle\},\{\langle x_1, ...x_k \rangle , x_{k+1} \}\}$

And this is where I am a bit stuck. I feel like you can just keep applying the Kuratowski definition until you get rid of all the angle brackets. At which point you work through the proof as in the base case of establishing the identity of the two sets. But I am not sure again what operations are permissible or necessary to complete this step.

Going back to the very beginning, I guess I don't know what functions A is supposed to be closed under. Like which function takes me from 2 to 3 in A, from 3 to 4, etc.  and so on?

Thanks for any and all help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Basically, for a formal proof, you have to exploit the formal definition. If we define the $n+1$-uple as a pair with first component an $n$-uple, assuming that the property holds for $n$-uples, the induction step is an application of the proof for pairs.

Comment: So just for my own clarification, in such a proof are we proving something about the all the natural numbers $\geq 2 $? Or something, about the structure of ordered pairs? Or, finally, is the proof exploiting the fact that we can model the latter on the former?

Comment: It is a "standard" proof by induction where $n$ is the "length" of the $n$-uple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for pairs define $(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.
Then its clear that

$(x_1,x_2) = (y_1,y_2)$ iff $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$.

Define $n$-tuples inductively as follows:

$(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}) := ((x_1,\ldots,x_n),x_{n+1})$, $n\geq 3$.

Suppose the result was proved for $n\geq 2$. Then

$(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}) = (y_1,\ldots,y_n,y_{n+1})$ iff by definition

$((x_1,\ldots,x_n),x_{n+1}) = ((y_1,\ldots,y_n),y_{n+1})$ iff by using equality of pairs,

$(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ and $x_{n+1} = y_{n+1}$ iff by induction hypothesis,

$x_1=y_1,\ldots,x_n=y_n,x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}$.